# Div doesn't display when using jScrollPane()

Tags: php, jquery, css, jscrollpane

This should be exceedingly simple, but here goes. I have a simple div container that gets populated by a Twitter feed (jTweetsAnywhere):

```
<div id='twitter-feed'></div>
```

This functionality works fine and gives me a simple container with a Twitter feed, with `overflow:auto`. Again: works fine, overflow is scrollable with the standard ugly scrollbar.

After loading jquery.jScrollPane.min.js, jquery.scrollpane.css, jquery.mousewheel.js, and mwheelintent.js, and initializing like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    . . .
    $("#twitter-feed").jScrollPane();
});
```

...the `#twitter-feed` div no longer displays, and no runtime error is thrown.

Thoughts?

Comment: OK, so the div isn't disappearing when I call `jScrollPane()` now, but the jScrollbar itself isn't showing up (and the default scrollbar disappears, making the div unscrollable. My CSS sets the height and width of the div explicitly, the overflow is set to `auto`, and the div is populated in JS prior to the `.jScrollPane()` call on it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess is that .jsScrollPane() is getting called long before jTweets returns anything.  This means that there is a good chance that it is setting the height of the container while its empty, so it probebly is set to 0.  Have you tried to give #twitter-feed a static height?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said originally that `#twitter-feed` _does_ have a static height set in CSS. Although you got me halfway there inadvertently: I was indeed calling `jScrollPane()` prior to initializing `jTweetsAnywhere` (stupid). So the `#twitter-feed` pane shows up now...however, it has no scrollbar at all and I actually can't scroll it, even with my mouse, even after clicking on it to ensure it has focus. Do I need to pass something into `jScrollPane()`? I wanted to try it with default settings first to make sure it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Having the same exact issue..and viewing Chrome built in debugger i've found our problem and posted in the jscrollpane google group..I'm almost afraid we might have to alter jTweetsAnywhere code to get this to work correctly..If this is true, I'll do it and make sure I post the solution here and a link...in a nutshell:

jTweetsAnywhere dynamically creates this before your jScrollPane call:

```
<div id="twitter-feed">
<div class="jta-tweets-list">
<ul><li>tweet</li><li>tweet</li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

After the jScrollPane call, your code inside the #twitter-feed container is modified to function like this:

```
<div id="twitter-feed">
<div class="jta-tweets-list">
<div class="jspContainer"><!-- I believe this is where the tweets <ul> needs to be loaded? --><div class="jspPane"></div></div>
<ul><li>tweet</li><li>tweet</li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`jScrollPane.js` has a nifty little method `autoReinitialise`, that when set to `true` basically adds a `setInterval()` that is constantly checking for the content within your target div.

Just make your call to `jScrollPane` **AFTER** your `jTweetsAnywhere` call:

```
$('.jta-tweets-list').jTweetsAnywhere({ stuff in here })
```

and pass it an object with `autoReinitialise: true`-

```
$('.jta-tweets-list').jScrollPane(
    {
        autoReinitialise: true
    }

);
```

Hope this helps!